# PhD student lost fellowship 1 week before school starts, what should I do?

Tags: phd, funding

I am a rising 2nd year PhD student in a US public school.

I was promised 4 years of funding by my department. Last year, I received a fellowship which covered tuition and stipend. I believe most people get 2 years of funding, so I was expecting it to be renewed. Over the summer, I kept asking about the status of my renewal application and only until yesterday (1 week before next school year) did they inform me my renewal was rejected. The secretary who communicates with me still has not told me why.

The next school year starts in <1 week, and all my classes will be dropped *tomorrow* if my tuition is not paid. To make matters worse, I am an international student, and if in ~3 weeks my tuition still isn't paid, then my visa will be invalidated and I fear I may be deported.

I will talk to my advisor tomorrow, but much advice is appreciated. In particular, I wish to know whether there is any standard procedure for this kind of situation and whether I should pay my own tuition first in case of any visa problem.

Comment: I presume you were promised 4 years of funding in your admission letter. That letter constitutes a contract. If the university refuses to honor the contract, seek lawyer's help.

Comment: @BorisBukh Obviously I am not in a position to know, but I would be surprised if the wording of the initial admission letter was unconditional. I can't imagine a graduate program committing themselves for 4 years to a student who might not pan out, especially if the anticipated funding was contingent on external grants. When I went to grad school, I remember being told that students can "normally" expect 4 years of funding, but nothing that would have made it certain.

Comment: @JohnColeman I agree that it depends on the wording; however, even an unfavorable wording might turn out to be unenforceable. Because of how much is at stake for the student is why I suggested to seek help of a professional.

Comment: @BorisBukh I agree that seeking a lawyer's help is unlikely to hurt, if it comes to that. Short of that, there might be a graduate student ombudsperson who could help.

Comment: @JohnColeman Mine was, at least for the first 12 months

Comment: I would not panic too much about having your classes dropped.  Once your funding is sorted out, they can be added again.  Even if they should somehow fill up in the meantime, since the registration issue was not your fault, your professors can and should let you take the class anyway (maximum class sizes can be overridden).

Comment: I don't know at which university you are studying, but a number of universities are experiencing severe financial difficulties recently. It may be that your university simply does not have the funds to renew your fellowship.

Comment: Please update after having talked to your advisor.

Answer (score 11):

> I wish to know whether there is any standard procedure for this kind of situation

You already have the right answer.  Talk to your advisor.

PhD students should never pay tuition.

Comment: Actually, if you don't have any funding, they you may well need to pay tuition. Some places only forgive part of the tuition even for TAs. So, while I agree with" _should_ never pay tuition", it doesn't always work that way.

Comment: Indeed, that's an incredibly STEM answer, @Anonymous Physicist, and you'd probably do well to find out a bit more about the funding situations of other disciplines before you make statements like that. While, indeed, the operative word there is "should", in many other disciplines the ideal simply is not the reality.

Comment: @GrotesqueSI I'm well aware that some PhD students get no support and must pay tuition.  And I know that's more common in the humanities.  And I strongly stand by what I said; don't pay tuition, even if it means not being a PhD student.

Comment: Unless you are telling the OP to *not* pay the tuition and drop out instead, it's not a helpful part of the answer.

Comment: @Anonymous Physicist Such an absolute statement ignores the complication and nuance of both PhD funding and motivation for doing a PhD. I mean, are you saying that if a student gets partial funding they should not do a PhD? If they have to fund one year but will have the rest funded they shouldn't do a PhD? That there's no circumstance where they should do a PhD part time while working part time? etc etc. I had only partial funding for mine, as it was funding meant for a local student and I was international, and I did it anyway, and am doing pretty great, frankly. Correct choice.

Comment: @GrotesqueSI Yes, I stand by what I said.  You have survivorship bias.  In fact, encouraging someone to complete a PhD without full funding is unethical, unless they are super rich.

Comment: @Anonymous Physicist Aha, so one exception now. Are there others? Without spending time understanding a student's context, motivation, and situation, how can you possibly speak to what they should or shouldn't do regarding how they spend their time and money? I'd argue it is unethical to do otherwise, and certainly makes for poor mentoring. Though I note, I didn't say anything about "encouraging" unfunded PhDs. I took issue with your "never" as untrue and unrealistic.

Comment: @Anonymous Physicist Note, PhDs likely cost significantly less where I am (Scotland) than where you are, assuming you are in the States. Undergraduate education is free here and PhDs are about 5300 USD/year full time and 2700 USD/year part time. Full time PhDs only last 3 years as students don't take any coursework.

Comment: Even if tuition is cheaper, you still need to shelter, feed, clothe, and entertain yourself.  It's much much easier to get funded as a PhD student than to get any academic job at any higher level.  So unless you're in a position to plop down a couple hundred thousand dollars purely for the fun of it, don't do an unfunded PhD.

Answer (score 5):

> I was promised 4 years of funding by my department. Last year, I received a fellowship...my renewal was rejected.

There are different types of funding -- teaching assistant, research assistant, and fellowship. If your fellowship application was rejected, then you should be awarded a TA or RA.

That said, you could still have problems. In particular, if you didn't apply for a TA or RA because you expected your fellowship to be renewed. Or if your funding was lost due to your actions (e.g., academic misconduct, poor performance, etc.).

> I will talk to my advisor tomorrow

Yes, absolutely this, talk to your advisor. Consider also talking to the graduate director or even international students' office -- and don't wait around for a response to e-mail, be proactive.

> I wish to know whether...I should pay my own tuition first in case of any visa problem.

If you pay your tuition with your own money, I would not expect to ever get that money back. On the other hand, if your visa expires, the university's ability to help you will be very limited.

Comment: "If you pay your tuition with your own money, I would not expect to ever get that money back." I don't agree with this. I have known departments that are untimely with getting appointments arranged, in which it wasn't uncommon for the paperwork to come after the deadline for tuition payment. However if an appointment includes remission of tuition as a benefit, it should be incompatible with the university's payroll procedures *not* to refund tuition already paid. This is from an American perspective, in case that's relevant.

Comment: *If* the university promised funding *and* the student held up their end, then I agree the university *should* return any money fronted. That is, however, two ifs and a should -- so, I would never advise a student to front money they can't afford on the assumption that they'll get it back. At least not without doing a ton of due diligence, which does not appear to have (yet) been done here.

Comment: Sure, the original phrasing seemed more to imply that there's no chance of getting a refund, as opposed to "make sure you know you'll get the money back before you forward potentially thousands of dollars [or local equivalent] from your bank account", which is pretty hard advice to argue with.

Comment: Talking to the advisor is always a good idea, but they are not likely to be the person who can actually solve this or give you an answer, though they may direct you to the person who can.  But to save time, I would also talk to the faculty member in charge of the graduate program ("graduate vice chair" or some similar title), who is most likely the person who actually will decide what kind of funding you will get instead.  And don't wait around for a response to an email - go talk to them in person.

Comment: It may also be a good idea to talk to the university's international student office, who can give specific advice about visa issues.  I wouldn't expect either the advisor or the graduate vice chair to be able to address that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this really sucks. I’m sorry to hear this happened.

> I was promised 4 years of funding by my department

In writing? Do you have an official letter from the university saying this or is it something more like “yeah most students get by you’ll be fine”

If you have any formal agreement/offer from your university for full funding then it’s not your problem how they fulfill it. If your stipend depends on teaching duties or something then you may need to do this now. To be honest, unless someone really screwed up it’s unlikely that your scholarship would lapse when the department committed to keeping you, so I suspect the promise you were given is less official than you might think.

If you are indeed a good “rising” student then your department/advisor will make significant efforts to keep you. If not, this may be their way of letting you go.